# How do I find nex page link when clicking on Load More button?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

Im trying to find where the next page link comes from.
The original page is  - [this](https://thekrazycouponlady.com/coupons-for/costco)
The link Im looking for has the following pattern - `https://api.krazy.com/v4/2/graphql?cache=967399174`
I can access the link and get all the headers to make it work. 
The problem is that I do not see how this link is generated. Search through the page source code and Dev Tools did not return any results for me.
Here is the code of the Load More button.

```
<kcl-load-more main-class="mb-25" on-click="addMorePosts()" model="latestPosts" model-loading="postsLoading" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div class="kcl-load-more mb-25" ng-class="vm.mainClass">

    <!-- ngIf: vm.model.length && !vm.hideIf --><button class="kcl-btn ng-scope" ng-class="vm.buttonClass" ng-click="vm.click()" ng-disabled="vm.loading || vm.modelLoading" ng-if="vm.model.length &amp;&amp; !vm.hideIf">
      <span class="hidden-side-scroll">LOAD MORE</span>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 35.09 34.39" height="32" width="32" aria-labelledby="title" class="icon visible-side-scroll">
            <title>Load More</title>
            <path fill="#3B3B3B" d="M35.09,17.19s0-.09,0-.13h0a1.31,1.31,0,0,0-.38-.78l0,0L18.82.38A1.31,1.31,0,0,0,17,2.23L30.62,15.88H1.31a1.31,1.31,0,0,0,0,2.62H30.62L17,32.15A1.31,1.31,0,1,0,18.82,34L34.67,18.15l0,0a1.31,1.31,0,0,0,.38-.79h0s0-.09,0-.14Z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button><!-- end ngIf: vm.model.length && !vm.hideIf -->
    <!-- ngIf: vm.model.length && !vm.hideIf --><div class="visible-side-scroll text-center ng-scope" ng-if="vm.model.length &amp;&amp; !vm.hideIf" ng-click="vm.click()">LOAD MORE</div><!-- end ngIf: vm.model.length && !vm.hideIf -->
</div>
</kcl-load-more>
```

How  is the `cache=967399174` part of the link generated?

Comment: It could be added before the page is sent to you

Comment: You should look at Network, it might tell you how post and get works.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel  but still i should see some unique part of code that triggers this , right?

Comment: Not necessarily, the generation of this cache id could be completly done in the backend

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel so there is no way to replicate this request with pure python rather then using web driver to execute javascript?

Comment: I would believe the generation of this id does more than creating the link. It probably fills the cache in the backend as well and you can't force a different server to do stuff for you